# Only first row data is inserted while using multiple array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have used four array in the form. While using only 2 array, it works. But more than 2 array (in following form) only **first student's first record is inserted**. I have tried using **multiple foreach**, but it doesn't solve problem. My PHP FORM output is as following.

```
<form method="post" action="mark.php">
<table id="customers">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th colspan="2"><input type="text" name="subjectid[]" value="Social"></th>
        <th colspan="2"><input type="text" name="subjectid[]" value="Math"></th>
        <th colspan="2"><input type="text" name="subjectid[]" value="English"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="stdname[]" value="John"></td>

        <td><input type="number" name="theory[]" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="practical[]" value=""></td>

        <td><input type="number" name="theory[]" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="practical[]" value=""></td>

        <td><input type="number" name="theory[]" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="practical[]" value=""></td>

    </tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="stdname[]" value="Rahul"></td>

        <td><input type="number" name="theory[]" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="practical[]" value=""></td>

        <td><input type="number" name="theory[]" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="practical[]" value=""></td>

        <td><input type="number" name="theory[]" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="practical[]" value=""></td>

    </tr>
</table>
    <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="submit"></input>
</form>
```

PHP CODE

```
<?php }
if(isset($_POST['submit1'])){
    $subjectid = $_POST['subjectid'];
    $theory = $_POST['theory'];
    $practical = $_POST['practical'];
    $stdname = $_POST['stdname'];

    foreach ($theory AS $key => $item) {               
        $sql = "INSERT INTO mark(subjectid, theory, practical, stdname) VALUES (:subjectid, :theory, :practical, :stdname)";
        $query = $con->prepare($sql);
        $query->bindParam(':subjectid', $subjectid[$key]);
        $query->bindParam(':theory', $theory[$key]);
        $query->bindParam(':practical', $practical[$key]);
        $query->bindParam(':stdname', $stdname[$key]);
        $query->execute();
        echo "<script>alert('Mark is inserted')</script>";
        echo("<script>window.location = 'mark.php';</script>");
        } 
}
?>
```

When Inserting following input
[image]

It is stored in database as
[image]

But It has to stored as
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `prepare` is getting cached with last statement. You probably write

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO mark(subjectid, theory, practical, stdname) VALUES (:subjectid, :theory, :practical, :stdname)";
$query = $con->prepare($sql);
foreach ($theory AS $key => $item) {
```

instead of

```
foreach ($theory AS $key => $item) {               
    $sql = "INSERT INTO mark(subjectid, theory, practical, stdname) VALUES (:subjectid, :theory, :practical, :stdname)";
    $query = $con->prepare($sql);
```

---

Other possibilities can be violation of any constraints, you might have unique key constraints on any of the column and trying to insert same value within the loop. You can verify by adding below line of code to your code.

```
echo $query->error;
```

Comment: same problem, only inserted first subject's record. I think my problem in foreach clause, array cannot be passed properly.

Comment: @AnandaLC could you share `$theory` output ?

Comment: Along $theory, every fields' output working fine. I've tested. Every field echo correct output as I typed. But while inserting, it doesn't work. Where is the problem ?

Comment: @AnandaLC could you post your table structure ? DDL ?

Comment: Please see my edited question with snapshot. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Use of Nested foreach works

```
foreach ($stdname AS $key => $item){
    $query->bindParam(':stdname', $stdname[$key]);
        foreach ($theory AS $key => $item) {               
            $query->bindParam(':subjectid', $subjectid[$key]);
            $query->bindParam(':theory', $theory[$key]);
            $query->bindParam(':practical', $practical[$key]);
            $query->execute();
        }
}
```